# Initialise a GUID variable: How?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am attempting to initialise a [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) variable but I not sure this is how you are meant to do it. What I am especially confused about is how to store the last 12 hexadecimal digits in the char array(do I include the "-" character?)

**How do I define/initialise a GUID variable?**

```
bool TVManager::isMonitorDevice(GUID id)
{
    // Class GUID for a Monitor is: {4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}

    GUID monitorClassGuid;
    char* a                = "bfc1-08002be10318"; // do I store the "-" character?
    monitorClassGuid.Data1 = 0x4d36e96e;
    monitorClassGuid.Data2 = 0xe325;
    monitorClassGuid.Data3 = 0x11ce;
    monitorClassGuid.Data4 = a;

    return (bool(id == monitorClassGuid));
}
```

Comment: Here is the way I did it when I was working with COM. [Create a GUID](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?280300-create-a-GUID-using-c)

Comment: How does this answer address the OP's question?

Comment: -1, this is not a useful/relevant answer, since it only creates brand-new GUIDs, rather than defining an existing known GUID, which is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `Data4` member is not a pointer, it's an array.  You'd want:

```
monitorClassGuid.Data4 = { 0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18 };
```

To make your example work.  You might find it easier to do all of the initialization along with the definition of your `monitorClassGuid` variable:

```
GUID monitorClassGuid = { 0x4d36e96e, 0xe325, 0x11c3, { 0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18 } };
```

Answer (score 6):

This question was asked long time ago, but maybe it helps somebody else.

You can use this code to initialize a GUID:

```
#include <combaseapi.h>;

GUID guid;
CLSIDFromString(L"{4d36e96e-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}", &guid);
```